# Android: Java: Proguard: How to: verify if my jar (different jar project)/apk are successfully processed? (I am thinking to reverse engineer it)

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, apk, proguard

I successfully processed my jar and apk. Then, want to verify if is it truly hard to reverse engineer or truly did the obfuscation.

I am thinking to try to reverse engineer it by myself to see what I did. But don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For manual reverse engineering, you can try [dex2jar](http://www.google.de/#q=dex2jar) and then [Java Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/).

Comment: i'll try that application. it seems that is the answer. +1

Comment: Thanks, that makes it pretty easy to check.  It's very interesting to go through my obfuscated code and see what's still there.  It's also a great reminder as to how much of your code is available if you don't obfuscate.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a set of tests (unit/functionality).  Run them against the obfuscated jar file.
They should pass as if you had the original program.

Comment: you may run the test classes successfully with or without obfuscation, ins't? So, how come we know or verify the obfuscated jar?