# Converting APK to JAR

Tags: java, android, jar, apk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [apk to jar convertor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7478874/802421)

In order to have a multiplatform application, i have a question a little special:

It's how to convert the file "APK" to "JAR".

Thanks for all

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) converts `.apk` to `.jar`, but you still have `.class` files in there. Those that do *not* link to the Android framework (which are probably only a few utility classes) should be reusable for another platform.

Using [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/) you can even look at the java code (most of the time at least)

And if you want to extract the resources (you probably need to images too if you want to "convert" it to a different platform) [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)

But there is absolutely no way to take an .apk and run it through a converter and have a Windows program.

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible - multiplatform requires a *bit* more work than just converting binaries - but thanks for the smile this question was putting on my face !-)

Comment: and what is the solution for my apk work on Windows or other platforms ??

Comment: @Zombie_Colonel run it in the emulator. It does not work otherwise. Or rewrite that apk so it runs on Windows.

Comment: @Zombie_Colonel please google for Bluestacks - claims that it can run apk's on windows, but as I do linux I have no clue how well it works - just read about it and wanted it for linux ;-)